# parametrize surface region

Tags: calculus, surfaces, parametric

S is the elliptic region of the plane $y+z=1$ inside the cylinder $4x^2+4(y-0.5)^2=1$.
First parametrize $S$ using $(x,y,z)=G(u,v)$ and then calculate $\displaystyle \frac{dG}{du}\times \frac{dG}{dv}$.

How can I parametrize this crazy region??

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Perhaps an additional question:  Find the centers of the Dandelin Spheres associated with this construction. Their points of tangency with the plane
are the foci of the ellipse.

The parametrization : $ x = u/2 \cos(v) , y = 1/2 + u/2 \sin(v) ,  z = 1/2 - u/2 \sin(v)$   with  $ v =[0,2\pi)$ and $ u = [0,1]$ seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
x&\equiv \half\,\cos\pars{\theta}\,,\quad
y \equiv \half + \half\,\sin\pars{\theta}\,,\quad
z = 1 - y = \half - \half\,\sin\pars{\theta}\,;\qquad\qquad 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi
\end{align}

> $$
> \vec{\rm r}\pars{\theta}
> =\half\braces{%
> \cos\pars{\theta}\,\hat{x} + \bracks{1 + \sin\pars{\theta}}\,\hat{y}
> + \bracks{1 - \sin\pars{\theta}}\,\hat{z}}
> $$

Comment: Almost. The set is two dimensional and requires two input variables, specified by $u$ and $v$ by the OP.